# How can I slove the error console only error in angular?

Tags: angular

src|sync:2 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'hammerjs'
at webpackEmptyContext (src|sync:2:1)
at main.ts:1:1
at environment.ts:8:3
at 14431 (environment.ts:8:3)
at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:19:1)
at **webpack_exec** (util.inspect:1:1)
at util.inspect:1:1
at **webpack_require**.O (chunk loaded:25:1)
at util.inspect:1:1
at webpackJsonpCallback (jsonp chunk loading:35:1)

I tried to remove in main.ts file some imports but its not work and after i can do these method it wont. npm uninstall hammerjs --save
then npm install hammerjs@latest